# Calculate web distance‽?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, arithmetic

I am doing the following programming exercise: [The Spider and the Fly (Jumping Spider)](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a30e7e9c5e28454790000c1). The statement is:

> Background
>
> A spider web is defined by
>
> ```
> "rings" numbered out from the centre as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> "radials" labelled clock-wise from the top as A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
> ```
>
> Here is a picture to help explain: [image: [source: imgur.com]]
>   Web Coordinates
>
> As you can see, each point where the rings and the radials intersect
>   can be described by a "web coordinate".
>
> So in this example the spider is at H3 and the fly is at E2 Kata Task
>
> Our friendly jumping spider is resting and minding his own spidery
>   business at web-coordinate spider.
>
> An inattentive fly bumbles into the web at web-coordinate fly and gets
>   itself stuck.
>
> Your task is to calculate and return the distance the spider must jump
>   to get to the fly. Example
>
> The solution to the scenario described by the picture is 4.63522 Notes
>
> ```
> The centre of the web will always be referred to as A0
> The rings intersect the radials at evenly spaced distances of 1 unit
> ```

I was trying to do by hand the calculus to solve the example:

Fist intuition was to give to each radial, a value:
A 0, B 1, C 2, D 3, E 4, F 5, G 6, H 7

Considering the example where we are at: x1,y1: H3 x2,y2: E2; it could be thought as x1,y1: 7,3 x2,y2: 4,2

Then my first way to try to solve the distance was to use: x2-x1 + y2-y1; 4-7 + 3-2 = 3+1 = 4

My second attempt to calculate the distance was with the [distance between two points](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html): [image]

$\displaystyle \sqrt{( 4-7)^{2} +( 2-3)^{2}}$ $\displaystyle =\ \sqrt{3^{2} +1^{2} \ } \ =\ \sqrt{10} \ =3,162277660168379‬\ $

As you see, none of the previous ideas achieve to calculate the example as it is been given in the exercise.

In addition I have also read:

- [A natural-looking distance formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304360/a-natural-looking-distance-formula)
- [To understand the distance function in (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344733/to-understand-the-distance-function-in-x-%C3%97-x)
- [Calculate distance between two points N,W,E,S](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21661/calculate-distance-between-two-points-n-w-e-s)

How could we calculate the web distance‽?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the complex plane and complex numbers. 
Assuming `A` is $0$, `B` is $1$, ...`H` is $7$, ..., the spider is on coordinates $(7,3)$ and the fly in on $(4,2)$. In the complex plane those places are $3 \left( \cos {\frac{3\pi}{4}}+i\sin {\frac{3\pi}{4}}\right)$ and $2 \left( \cos {\frac{3\pi}{2}}+i\sin {\frac{3\pi}{2}}\right)$. So, in the algebraic form, we have $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$ for the location of the spider and $-2i$ for the location of the fly. Now you can calculate the absolute value of the difference between those values to get the distance:

$$d=\left|\left(-\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)-\left(-2i\right)\right| =\sqrt{\left( \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)^2+\left(2+ \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)^2  } \approx 4.63522$$

For a general formula, you just have to repeat the process keeping in mind that a set of coordinates $(a,b)$ in the web system corresponds to the complex number $b \left( \cos {\frac{(2-a)\pi}{4}}+i\sin {\frac{(2-a)\pi}{4}}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
d= \sqrt{\left( 2+ \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 } = 4.6522 \cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}